# Class not found while using composer and docker

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

Im using this library https://serp-spider.github.io/documentation/search-engine/google/

When I follow their example I got this.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Serps\SearchEngine\Google\GoogleClient" not found in /var/www/html/index.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 19
```

This is my index.php

```
<?php
  
    use Serps\SearchEngine\Google\GoogleClient;
    use Serps\SearchEngine\Google\GoogleUrl;

    $googleClient = new Serps\SearchEngine\Google\GoogleClient($httpClient);

    $googleUrl = new GoogleUrl();
    $google->setSearchTerm('simpsons');

    $response = $googleClient->query($googleUrl);

    $results = $response->getNaturalResults();

    foreach($results as $result){
        // Here we iterate over the result list
        // Each result will have different data based on its type
    }

  ?>
```

I've been thinking about what it could be for a while but I can't

Comment: Looks like you're missing to include the autoload.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the autoload, I added this line and works.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the namespace and forgot to update it in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyNamespace\\": "src"
    }
},
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload`